# importing files that are 4 folders deep

Tags: reactjs, import, ecmascript-6, jsx

I'm trying to figure out how to import a file in my src/assets folder. The file is called Current.jpg.

The file I want to use that image in is in src/components/footer/overview folder.

To me, that means I should be able to write:

```
import Current from '..../assets/Current.jpg';
```

That means going up 4 folder levels to src and then to assets and then to the file called Current.jpg.

I keep getting an error saying that path is incorrect.

How do you traverse 4 folder layers? Is there a trick that you need to be able to go deeper than 2?

Comment: Is there any reason to have a top-level `assets`? Could you consider putting the image inside the component, or making a new component to represent the image itself?

Comment: I don't know how to do either of those things. Thanks for the suggestions, Ill research how to set them up this evening

Comment: Check this out.. https://medium.com/@goangle/webpack-resolve-import-require-path-that-refers-to-root-directory-by-resolve-root-1775fdc5723b

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`import Current from '../../../assets/Current.jpg`

You only need to go up 3 directories, and then down 1 into assets.

To tidy up those imports, you could look at [webpack resolve](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/) if you are using webpack to add an alias to the `src/assets` folder so you could do:

`import Current from 'Assets/Current.jpg`

It would be as simple as:

```
resolve: {
    alias: {
        Assets: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/assets')
    }
}
```

Comment: Do 2 dots represent a single folder layer? I thought it was one dot for each folder layer. Anyway, I tried this suggestion - it produces a different error: Uncaught Error: Module parse failed: /Users/18/src/assets/Current.jpg Unexpected character '�' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
(Source code omitted for this binary file)

Comment: 2 dots is to go up 1 directory; a single dot is the current directory. I think you need an image or file loader for webpack which is a different question to this one

Comment: Thanks Tony. I tried to add your alias suggestion to my webpack config, but it generates an error that says; Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration has an unknown property 'alias'. These properties are valid:

Comment: `alias` is a property of `resolve` in the config; but this won't solve the image loading problem you are having - just a cleaner way for those deeply nested imports

Comment: Thanks Tony. Can you give me a reference to the type of problem you think I'm having so that I can try to research in a different direction. I don't know why I can't use images in react.

Comment: This doesn't work - but marking correct as a sign of thanks for trying to help me.

Comment: This is the answer to your question about how to traverse the folders; to solve the error that you are getting now that you are importing check out https://webpack.js.org/loaders/file-loader/ - that is what you need

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try changing `import Current from '..../assets/Current.jpg';` to           `import Current from ../../../../assets/Current.jpg';`?

Comment: That doesnt work either. I think a single dot represents a folder layer, so I'm not sure the 2 dots between a backslash works anyway. Thanks anyway for the suggestion.

Comment: Oh, I miscounted the layers to go up. By the way, I think Tony's answer is better.